# Is it possible to ignore errors on DROP VIEW IF EXISTS xxx (Object found is of type TABLE)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If have a

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS mydatabase.myschema.myname;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  mydatabase.myschema.myname AS ...
```

that fails with error code 2203 `SQL compilation error: Object found is of type 'TABLE', not specified type 'VIEW'.`.

My intention was to create a script to "convert" a set of existing views into tables (updated periodically via tasks). I wanted the script to be repeteable, so I thought I could `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS xxx` to drop the view if it exists but it seems that this will fail if there is already a table of the same name. So first time the script runs ok, it drops the view and creates the table but if I run the script again it will fail because now there is table with that same name.

So is there any way to ignore the error in the `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS xxx` or just to run the command if there is a VIEW with that name?

Comment: good idea, maybe you could share the result with us :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options.

You can have your script read from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get a list of views and to delete. This SQL gets a list of all views except in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA';
```

If you just want to drop the view names and avoid running into errors, here's a stored procedure you can call to try dropping a view without generating an error:

```
create or replace procedure DropView(viewName string)
returns string
language JavaScript
execute as OWNER
as
  $$  
    var sql_command = 
    'drop view ' + VIEWNAME;
    try {
            var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} );
            var resultSet = stmt.execute();        
            while (resultSet.next())  {
                outString = resultSet.getColumnValue('status');
            }
        }
    catch (err)  {
        outString = err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
        }
   return outString;
  $$;
```

If you want to loop through every database and schema in the entire account, I wrote a stored procedure to do that. It's designed for dependency checking on all views, but could be modified to delete them too.

https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2019/10/14/object-dependency-checking-in-snowflake

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a stored procedure that loops through all of your views and creates tables from them.  In that stored procedure, you could check to see if the object exists already as a table and skip that object.

Comment: How would you skip the object? would you modify Greg's stored procedure to add skip file in the catch(err) clause and pass in a list of views instead?

Comment: I'd query information_schema.tables for only records where the views don't exist as tables, and then only execute the statements for that list.

Answer (score 0):

Using Snowflake Scripting block and checking metadata tables:

```
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT * 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
             WHERE TABLE_NAME   ILIKE 'TEST' 
               AND TABLE_SCHEMA ILIKE 'PUBLIC')) THEN
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS PUBLIC.TEST;
  END IF;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PUBLIC.TEST AS SELECT 1 AS c;
END;
```